# Error on App Engine Application creation with Terraform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I currently getting the following error when I run my Terraform Script on my google cloud project:

`Error: Error creating App Engine application: googleapi: Error 409: This application already exists and cannot be re-created., alreadyExists`

I know it's because it is already running from when I set up a cloud on that project before and used **terraform destroy** .
In the Documentation of terraform is mentioned, that it currently can not delete it when it's created.

Is there any way I can get around that? Didn't find anything about Error handling or something. Only other method would be two sperate scripts for setting up a cloud environment (with and withoud the app engine application)

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what you are trying to do, if you are following any guide, it seem that Terraform is try to run the command “gcloud projects create” for a project that already exists.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is the limitation of Terraform.
Terraform is not able to delete App Engine application when you run terraform destroy command.

Two solutions I can think of

1. Delete the project and recreate it if you are creating full infrastructure using terraform.
2. Create app manually using `gcloud app create`

Comment: This is a GAE limitation. An App engine cannot currently be deleted. However, you can delete the entire project by going to IAM --> Settings --> Shut Down. This button is in the header and a bit tricky to spot.

Comment: It's a well-known GCP limitation, but Terraform should absolutely be able to skip it instead of throwing an error.

Comment: @shemsu, Yes I agree, this is well known limitation.